# Can i dynamically call a getter using mapGetters in Vue/Vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

My component template:

```
<template>
  <section class="stage my-5">

      <div class="stage-heading">
        <h3 class="stage-number mb-4">Stage {{stage}}</h3>
        <h6 class="stage-hrs">Total Hrs: {{totalHours}}</h6>
      </div>

      <div class="stage-courses card text-white bg-info mb-3" v-for="course in courses" :key="course.id">
        <div class="card-header">Stage {{course.stage}}</div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{course.title}}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">{{course.creator}}</p>
          <p class="card-text">{{course.hours}} Hours</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </section>
</template>
```

The state in my Vuex store:

```
const state = {
  roadmapStage1: [], 
  roadmapStage2: [],
  roadmapStage3: [],  
};
```

I have getters in my Vuex store that look like:

```
getRoadmapStage1: state => state.roadmapStage1,
getRoadmapStage2: state => state.roadmapStage2,
getRoadmapStage3: state => state.roadmapStage3,
```

I'm trying to dynamically call one of these getters from a component, which one depends on a prop of the component:

```
export default {
  name: "Stage",
  data() {
    return {
      courses: []
    }
  },
  props: ['stage'],
  computed: mapGetters({courses: 'getRoadmapByStage'})
}
```

Is there any way to insert the prop into the 'getRoadmapByStage'? e.g. so it functions like 
`getRoadmapByStage${stage}`?

Ultimately i'm trying to get the component to re-render anytime one the roadmapStage arrays are updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using a getter with a parameter for the stage id/number that returns the roadmap you want, like so:

```
// in getters.js
//gets the current roadmap based on the stage number
getRoadmapByStage: (state) => (stageNumber) => {
    return state["roadmapStage" + stageNumber];
}
```

now in your component you can have:

```
computed: {
   currentRoadmap() {
      // now we'll pass in your 'stage' prop to get the appropriate map
      // this will re-render the component as that prop changes
      return this.$store.getters.getRoadmapByStage(this.stage);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, my component isn't re-rendering though or showing anything. I think it's because the 'courses' piece of data isn't being changed and the v-for relies on this piece of data. I've edited my question to show the template. Do I need to set the state within `currentRoadmap()` instead of just returning it? Vue is confusing the hell out of me at the moment!

Comment: Forget that! I've figured it, just needed to change `v-for="course in courses"` to `v-for="course in currentRoadmap"`. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your computed `roadmap` property as follows:

```js
computed: {
  roadmap() {
    return this.stage ? this.$store.getters['getRoadmapByStage' + this.stage] : undefined
  },
}
```

That way you are getting the roadmap by the value of the prop or `undefined` if the prop is not set to anything.